# how to retrieve profile after login using session php

Tags: php, session

I have been having trouble with retrieving profile page after login I have no Idea how to start I have all the codes for login I don't know how to use session to display profile information after login please help me I don't know what else to do

**login.php**

```
<?php
include('com.php');

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$email = stripslashes($email);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $email and $password, table row must be 1 row
if ($count == 1) {

    // Register $email, $password and redirect to file "report.php"
    session_register("email");
    session_register("password");
    header("location:profile.php");
} else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: does this go on the top of the login.php Salim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Send user email id using get method in header

login.php

```
header("Location: profile.php?email=$email");
                 ^ must be a space here
```

Then get it in profile page

profile.php

```
$email= $_GET["email"];
```

Show data here from database which matches with $email

2.Another way useing session

login.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["email"] = $email;
$_SESSION["password"] = $password; 
header("Location: profile.php");
```

get this value from profile page

profile.php

```
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
```

Show data here from database which matches with $email

Comment: `header("Location: profile.php");` *"L must be capital"* - `L` doesn't need to be capitalized. Just as long as there is a space after the semi-colon. Plus if there is a space after `Location` as in `header("Location : file.php` or `header("Location :file.php`, are both invalid.

Comment: DOES THIS GO ON LOGIN.PHP?

Comment: to retrieve profile page does email and password need to be in the same table as profile information? if so how can I intergrade email and password to profile table?

Answer (score 1):

`session_register` has been deprecated since php 5.3 and removed as of php 5.4. Dont use it.

To answer your question, you need to first assign the user to a session variable...

`$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;`

Then on subsequent page requests...

`$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . (int) $_SESSION['user_id'];`

There are much better ways to write this. This is just a simple example to get you on the right track.

Comment: This first, `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id`, goes in your login function after you authenticate the user. The next goes wherever you need to access the logged in user's information.